# Hover for div to increase its size dynamically

Tags: html, css

how to add hover for div(card) which increases the size (width and height) dynamically, because I don't want write every size increase in media for responsive.

This doesn't work:

```css
.card:hover {
    background-color: #ffd700;
    width: 260px;
    height: 293px; 
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  hello
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for more about what this site is, and how much is expected of those who ask questions.

Comment: @front-g Hey there, welcome to SO! I have edited your post and removed all the unrelated stuff. Please have a look at the resources provided in the comment above. Next time, I will also just downvote such a question.

Comment: One way to do it is to give the **div.card** an initial size.  And the **div.card:hover** would have a larger size.

Answer (score 1):

use `tranform:scale(1.5)` to scale times 1.5

```css
.card {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 260px;
  height: 293px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #ffd700;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  hello
</div>
```